# Want to display HTML data that contains both nested and non-nested tables within my Flutter application

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-html

I am currently using a plugin **(flutter_html 2.2.1)** to display HTML data that contains both nested and non-nested tables within my Flutter application. The code I have provided below is used to display the tables, but it only allows me to show the non-nested tables within a scrollable view. I am seeking a solution that would enable me to display both the nested and non-nested tables in a single scrollable view. Can you please suggest a solution to this issue?

**Html data coming from API:-**

```
"
<body>
   \r\n\r\n
   <h2>SQL NUMERIC/MATH FUNCTIONS</h2>
   \r\n
   <p>A mathematical function performs a mathematical operation on numeric values and return a numeric value as a result of the operation.</p>
   \r\n
   <p>Arithmetic functions, such as ABS, CEILING, DEGREES, FLOOR, POWER, RADIANS, and SIGN, return a value having the same data type as the input value. Trigonometric and other functions, including EXP, LOG, LOG10, SQUARE, and SQRT, cast their input values to float and return a float value.</p>
   \r\n
   <p>All mathematical functions, except for RAND, are deterministic functions. This means they return the same results each time they are called with a specific set of input values. RAND is deterministic only when a seed parameter is specified.</p>
   \r\n\r\n
   <h3>NUMERIC/MATH FUNCTIONS</h3>
   \r\n
   <p>The following table details various numeric/math functions:</p>
   \r\n\r\n
   <table id=\"customers\">
      \r\n  \r\n    
      <tr>
         \r\n      
         <th align=\"center\"><b>Function</b></th>
         \r\n      
         <th align=\"center\"><b>Description & Example</b></th>
         \r\n    
      </tr>
      \r\n \r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">ABS</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the absolute value of a number<br/>\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT ABS(5);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> ABS(5) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>5</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">ACOS</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the arc cosine of a number <br/>\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT ACOS(1);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> ACOS(1) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>0</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">ASIN</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the arc sine of a number<br/>\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT ASIN(1);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b>ASIN(1) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>1.5707963267949 </td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">ATAN</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the arc tangent of a number <br/>\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT ATAN(1);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> ATAN(1) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>0.785398163397448</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">ATN2</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the arc tangent of two numbers<br/>\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT ATN2(5,2);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> ATN2(5,2) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>1.19028994968253</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">CEILING</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the smallest integer value that is greater than and equal (>=) to a number\r\n<br/>\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT CEILING(25.75);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> CEILING(25.75) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>26</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">COS</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the cosine of a number  <br/><br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT COS(1);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> COS(1) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>0.54030230586814</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">COT</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the cotangent of a number<br/>\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT COT(1);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> COT(1) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>0.642092615934331</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">DEGREES</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Converts a value in radians to degrees  <br/><br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT DEGREES(5);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> DEGREES(5) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>286</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">EXP</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns e raised to the power of a specified number  <br/>\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT EXP(2);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> EXP(2) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>7.38905609893065</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">FLOOR\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the largest integer value that is greater than and equal (<=) to a number  <br/>\r\n<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT FLOOR(25.75);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> FLOOR(25.75) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>25</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">LOG\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the natural logarithm of a number, or the logarithm of a number to a specified base  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT LOG(5);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> LOG(5) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>1.6094379124341</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">LOG10\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the natural logarithm of a number to base 10  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT LOG10(5);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> LOG10(5) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>0.698970004336019</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">PI\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the value of PI  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT PI();\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> PI( ) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>3.14159265358979</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">POWER\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the value of a number raised to the power of another number  <br/>\r\n<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT POWER(3, 2);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> POWER(3, 2) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>9</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">RADIANS\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Converts a degree value into radians  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT RADIANS(90);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> RADIANS(90) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>1</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">RAND\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns a random number  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT RAND();\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> RAND( )</b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>0.149683153611311</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">ROUND\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Rounds a number to a specified number of decimal places  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT ROUND(235.415, 2);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> ROUND(235.415, 2) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>235.420</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">SIGN\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the sign of a number  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT SIGN(250.5);</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> SIGN(250.5)</b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>1.0</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">SIN\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the sine of a number  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT SIN(1);</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> SIN(1)</b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>0.841470984807897</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">SQRT\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the square root of a number  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT SQRT(49);</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> SQRT(49) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>7</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">SQUARE\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the square of a number  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT SQUARE(12);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> SQUARE(12)</b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>144</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
      <tr>
         \r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">TAN\r\n</td>
         \r\n\r\n
         <td valign=\"top\">
            <b>Returns the tangent of a number  <br/>\r\n\t<br/></b>\r\n\r\n
            <div class=\"containerExample\">SQL>&nbsp SELECT TAN(1);\r\n</div>
            \r\n\r\n
            <p>The above query would produce the following result:</p>
            \r\n\r\n
            <table  id=\"customers\">
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  </th>\r\n
                  <th align=center><b> TAN(1) </b></th>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n\r\n
               <tr>
                  \r\n
                  <td>1.5574077246549</td>
                  \r\n
               </tr>
               \r\n
            </table>
         </td>
         \r\n\r\n
      </tr>
      \r\n\r\n\r\n
   </table>
   \r\n\r\n\r\n
</body>
\r\n</html>"
```

**my Flutter  code:-**

```
Html(
  customRender: {
    "table": (context, child) {
      return Container(
        child: Scrollbar(
          thumbVisibility:
              true, //always show scrollbar
          thickness:
              5, //width of scrollbar
          radius: Radius.circular(
              30), //corner radius of scrollbar
          scrollbarOrientation:
              ScrollbarOrientation
                  .bottom,
          child: Container(
            padding:
                EdgeInsets.only(
                    bottom: 10),
            child:
                SingleChildScrollView(
              physics:
                  BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              scrollDirection:
                  Axis.horizontal,
              child: (context
                          .tree
                      as TableLayoutElement)
                  .toWidget(
                      context),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  },
  data: snapshot
      .data!
      .resultList![index]
      .topicWEB,
  onLinkTap:
      (url, _, __, ___) async {
    print("Opening $url...");
  },
  onCssParseError:
      (css, messages) {
    print(
        "css that errored: $css");
    print("error messages:");
    messages.forEach((element) {
      print(element);
    });
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Flutter html is not that good in handling tables. You can use flutter_inappwebview.

It will automatically handle the tables under html data.